# Extending SQLException - errors from baseclass throw

Tags: java, exception

(getting back to Java after a long absence)

In short: have existing code that throws **SQLException**. I want to trap these events. I've created a class that extends SQLException and tried updating the **throws** declaration of a function but am getting compile errors.

> java: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Is what I'm trying to do permitted? If not, is there a way to trap a predefined exception in a subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: if you add the throws declaration to your method, the exception you are "**throwing**" should be "**thrown**" somewhere in the method body.

Yes, you can extend `SQLException` if you want a kind of a "b*usiness SQL exception*" I suggest you to **catch** (not trap) `SQLException` where it may occur and then **throw** your own exception which extends `SQLException`.

**EDIT:**
If you don't know how catch keyword works, here is an example of catching SQLException:

```
public void executeQuery(String sql) {
  try {
    // do some database connection which can throw SQLException
  } cathc (SQLException e) {
    // send this exception via mail
  }
}
```

Comment: So it isn't sufficient to let the existing method (which 'throws SQLException') remain as-is and change the declaration to 'throws mynewexception'? I need to trap the SQLException in the method and then throw mynewexception()?

Comment: Yes you need to catch SQLException and then throw new YourNewException();  but think twice, usually it's not required

Comment: 'usually it's not required' - ?? My assigned task is to trap SQLExceptions and send some mail. Hence the subclass.

Comment: I mean that usually you can write your logic using standard exceptions, not extending them with your own, on my experience very rare. But of course it depends on what you want to do. Ask yourself do you really need to subclass SQLException if you need to just send the stacktrace via email?

Comment: if you don't know how catch works please see my edit in the answer